# Running tomcat inside Jboss server

Tags: tomcat, jboss, webserver, application-server

In my project, setup comes with `Jboss(3.0.4.GA) application server`. But I am in need of deploying only `.war` files. So I no need a application server to do my task. When I am looking some docs related to jboss ([Jboss arch](http://jbossweb.jboss.org/arch.html)) I found that

> JBoss Web Server comes with various extension modules that extends the
>   core functionality of both Apache Tomcat standalone, and standard
>   JBoss Application Server.

**Apache Tomcat standalone** - Is this capable of running alone? Is there any way to run `Apache tomcat` alone which is available inside `Jboss`?

Note: I could not add tomcat server in setup.

Comment: Wow, you really mean JBoss 3.0.4 like "released in 2002"? That's really old...

Comment: @piet.t Yes, I am working in very old project.

Comment: If you already have a JBoss environment up and running and everything works, I wouldn't mess with it too much. Is there a problem you are actually trying to solve? If you just don't feel like the complexity of JBoss is worth it or is adding too much overhead, then switch completely to Tomcat: don't try to figure out how to launch *only* the Tomcat that comes with JBoss. This will also give you an opportunity to upgrade to a version of Tomcat that was released withing the current decade.